# GRX 815 STIs with XT 8120 4-piston caliper?

Tags: compatibility, grx

I want to use the XT 8120 4-piston caliper to my GRX 815 STIs to increase my braking power. After researching, I still haven't found a definite answer. I've also looked into the Hope RX4+ 4-piston calipers, however there are some users complaining with difficulty in fully bleeding the calipers due to the design.

Any one out there tried running STIs with 4-pot calipers?

Comment: I run first-gen RX-4 and the bleed is pretty much the same as other MTB/road calipers.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: my 2-piston 8100 brakes produce way more than enough stopping power. Under what conditions are yours not enough?

Answer (score 2):

Hm. Let’s think about this for a second. Info is specific to Shimano:

- Flat mount MTB calipers are just relabeled road calipers. Therefore, MTB levers can properly actuate road calipers.
- Accordingly, since road levers and MTB levers can both actuate a 2-piston caliper, one can then deduce that road levers can properly actuate MTB 2-piston calipers.
- Since 2-piston and 4-piston MTB calipers use the same levers, one can therefore conclude than road levers can actuate 4-piston MTB calipers.

Of course, the logic is funky at best, but at least there’s no glaring reason for incompatibility.

---

- The exception is Saint/Zee levers, which I believe use a smaller piston in the lever to generate more power, but that is irrelevant.

Comment: This is my understanding as well. Stay out of the Saint/Zee/Dura-Ace/XTR zone and things should "just work"